# Python3 Динамичный символ

Tags: python, python-3.x

**Как сделать динамичный символ [/] чтоб он крутился по часовой стрелке.** Как в pip когда устанавливается пакет. Или же чтоб поочередно печатались символы с задержкой допустим в 0.5 секунды. П (0.5 сек) Р (0.5 сек) И (0.5 сек) и т.д

Comment: Вам нужен прогресс-бар?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import sys
import time

def spinning_cursor():
    while True:
        for cursor in '|/-\\':
            yield cursor

spinner = spinning_cursor()
for _ in range(50):
    sys.stdout.write(next(spinner))
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(0.1)
    sys.stdout.write('\b')
```